# How could I verify that a contract was actually sent to me from the client as soon as the contract is received?

Tags: encryption, signature, algorithm-design, encoding

with the information provided - what would be the best solution - something like document management program like IBM Filenet ? or trusted timestamping?

If I want to store electronic contracts for clients over a long period of time. I need to make sure that those files are not readable by anyone other than the client until the client retrieves them at a later time. But, I do need to be able to verify that a contract was actually sent to me from the client as soon as the contract is received. How could this be done? what would the client do, and what algorithms would they use? What would I do, and what algorithms would I use?

Comment: What if the contract deliberately doesn't touch the e-mail for a long time? Not a clear question.

Comment: assume a normal scenerio

Comment: This is Cryptography. There is no normal (ideal) scenario here. If all is normal then there is no need for encryption at all, everybody plays the game ideally, done. What if the client is a covert adversary?

Comment: touché what I meant to say was, with the information provided - what would be the best solution - something like document management program like IBM Filenet ? or trusted timestamping?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify with every detail!.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to verify and what your threat model is. It sounds like you want to detect when X happens instead of Y - what are X and Y?